# Jquery not firing click() to fire with a div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In my erb file, I have a script like this:

```
function checkJquery() {
  if(window.jQuery) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert('onready');
        $('div#habla_topbar_div').click(function() { 
            alert('onclick');
        });
    });
 }
 else {
    window.setTimeout(checkJquery, 1000);
 } 
}
```

I get the 'onready' alert, but the 'onclick' alert does not work. Any idea what I might doing wrong?

Edit:
The div is part of the Olark chat integration and the erb file has nothing except the configuration for that and the above script.

The div 'habla_topbar_div' is defined.
Image:
[image: via 'Inspect Element']

Comment: what is `'div#habla_topbar_div'`? put your html code too. it seems your problem is using selectors.

Comment: There's no div with id 'habla_topbar_div' available.

Comment: Do you have a `div` with attribute `id="habla_topbar_div"`?

Comment: can you post your `html.erb` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several Rails-specific issues here

--

**Delegation**

Because most Rails applications use `Turbolinks` or similar, you have to [`delegate` your Javascript](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) (typically) from the `document` object:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#habla_topbar_div", function() { 
     alert('onclick');
});
```

If you use this without embedding with other JS functions, it should work, considering you have a div with `id=habla_topbar_div`.

--

**Turbolinks Events**

Secondly, you want to ensure you replace the standard `$(document).ready` function with one of the [Turbolinks event hooks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events). You'll want to do the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var your_function = function(){
  ...
}
$(document).on("page:load ready", your_function);
```

Comment: Thanks! The Turbolinks part is what I was missing. Works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, maybe you don't have a `div` with `id="habla_topbar_div"`.

[**Check this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/861up2h1/1/) to find out where did you wrong.

**Update:**

If you already have a `div` with `id="habla_topbar_div"` maybe the Id's value has been changed by some code or application before rendering or on runtime.

Try to add an unique class name to "habla_topbar_div" `div` like this:

```
<div id="habla_topbar_div" class="habla_topbar_div_unique habla_topbar_div_normal ...">
```

and use this:

```
$('.habla_topbar_div_unique').click
```

instead of this:

```
$('div#habla_topbar_div').click
```

**[Check Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/861up2h1/2/)**

Comment: I do have a div with that name. Check the attached screeenshot that I have added.

Comment: please look at your rendered code after opened in browser and check that is the `id="habla_topbar_div"` changed to another value by your application or not.